# Parallel assignments in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following bash script:

```
for (( i = 1; i <= $3; i++ ))
do
    x=$($1 bench 4 2>&1|grep "Nodes\/second"|sed "s/.*: \([0-9]*\)/\1/") &
    y=$($2 bench 4 2>&1|grep "Nodes\/second"|sed "s/.*: \([0-9]*\)/\1/")
    echo $x, $y
done
```

Which I run with 3 parameters:

1. first program: result of `$($1 bench 4 2>&1|grep "Nodes\/second"|sed "s/.*: \([0-9]*\)/\1/")` is a number.
2. second program. idem.
3. number of iterations

The key thing is that I want to run the `x=...` and `y=...` in parallel, which is why I use an ampersand. This is important and parallelization has to be done this way (run first iteration for x and y, wait for both to complete before second iteration etc.)

The result of this script is that x is not assigned, and only y is:

```
$ ./bench.sh ./Stockfish/cerr ./Stockfish/master 50
, 2417071
, 2440128
, 2439481
etc.
```

Why?

Comment: You can fold the grep filter into sed: `$1 bench 4 2>&1 | sed -n '/Nodes\/second/s/.*: \([0-9]*\)/\1/p'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that you have to put both of them in the background (so put and ampersand at the end of both line) and then `wait` for the jobs to complete -- if not you are not sure the first job is finished before the second iteration starts.

The second problem is that you cannot get the output back from a background job with `x$(...)&`, so you will have to redirect the output to a file and then read the file output when the job is done.

```
for (( i = 1; i <= $3; i++ ))
do
    ($1 bench 4 2>&1|grep "Nodes\/second"|sed "s/.*: \([0-9]*\)/\1/" >/tmp/x) &
    ($2 bench 4 2>&1|grep "Nodes\/second"|sed "s/.*: \([0-9]*\)/\1/" >/tmp/y) & 
    wait
    read x </tmp/x
    read y </tmp/y
    echo $x, $y
done
```

**Also** as an extra bonus answer, try read the man page for `xargs` -- in most cases it makes these kind of loops quite unnecessary and a lot safer.

Comment: Thank you. That works perfectly. I was naively hoping for something simpler, not involving temporary files, but couldn't do it.